# How to extract the lines containing the letters into an array from a text file?

Tags: python

I would like to know how to extract the names (letters) from a text file and put it into an array. The text file is a "Booklist"; it contains names of books and reference numbers and I would like to extract the names of the books into an array. I know how to do the reference numbers but not the book names. if there's anyone can help me, I would appreciate it.

Here's the text file:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ayinnc83poulhv7/Booklist.txt?dl=0

```
The Adventures of Tom Sawyer
2
Huckleberry Finn
4
The Sword in the Stone
6
Stuart Little
10
Treasure Island
12
The Secret Garden
14
Alice's Adventures in Wonderland
20
Twenty Thousand Leagues Under the Sea
24
Peter Pan
26
Charlotte's Web
31
A Little Princess
32
Little Women
33
Black Beauty
35
The Merry Adventures of Robin Hood
40
Robinson Crusoe
46
Anne of Green Gables
50
Little House in the Big Woods
52
Swiss Family Robinson
54
The Lion, the Witch and the Wardrobe
56
Heidi
66
A Winkle in Time
100
Mary Poppins
```

This is my current code:

```
number_list = []
#Put reference number into arrays
with open("Booklist.txt","r") as fp:
    line_list = fp.readlines()
    for line in line_list:
        line = line.rstrip()
        try:
            number_list.append(int(line))
        except:
            pass
print(number_list)
```

Output:

```
[2, 4, 6, 10, 12, 14, 20, 24, 26, 31, 32, 33, 35, 40, 46, 50, 52, 54, 56, 66, 100]
```

But I also want it to put the name of the books into an array too; separately from the first array as shown above.

Comment: I have made it more easier to look at and understand what I'm asking for. Thanks for replying.

Comment: Thank you for responding to the feedback. A super simple modification to your current approach would be to use the `except` to append to a different list containing book names. But that relies on there being no books called "21" or similar. Does the posted answer work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use the except block as the following:

```
with open("Booklist.txt","r") as fp:
        line_list = fp.readlines()
        number_list = []
        name_list = []
        for line in line_list:
            line = line.rstrip()
            try:
                number_list.append(int(line))
            except:
                name_list.append(line)
        print number_list
        print name_list
```

Comment: Wow! It works. I would never have thought that is that simple. I guess I was over thinking things. Thanks my dude.

Comment: yeah it happens most of the time =) can you accept my answer then? :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `isdigit()` method to check whether the given line is digit or not.

```
with open("Booklist.txt","r") as fp:
    lines = fp.readlines()
number_list = [line.strip() for line in lines if line.strip().isdigit()]
```